# Excel Function (employee time-sheet): Subtract one hour for lunch each day

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need the calendar to add up the hours worked for each day, and subtract 1 hour each day for lunch automatically. Below is the code that I have used for the Excel function, but it needs to be fixed to take a hour out for each day for lunch. Right now it is adding up the hours fine but I can not figure out how to subtract an hour for lunch each day.

So for example, below in the illustration it shows 16 hours for Monday and Tuesdays work hours, when really it should show 14 hours because of the 2 hours out for lunch for the two days.

If someone knows, can you please help me to figure this out. Thanks, in advance.

**Here is a link to the Excel file:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/121i-3DQ30Zs_UHI4w1QPak8WaQk7_qb0/view?usp=sharing

**Code:** =IF(((D5-C5)+(F5-E5)+(H5-G5)+(J5-I5)+(L5-K5)+(N5-M5))*24>40,40,((D5-C5)+(F5-E5)+(H5-G5)+(J5-I5)+(L5-K5)+(N5-M5))*24)

[image]

Comment: Subtract `COUNTA(C5:N5)/2` from the total (assuming each day worked has both an "In" and "Out" value, and those values span the lunch hour)

Comment: also use MAX fomula to limit the hours to 40: `MAX((D5-C5)+(5F-E5)+...+(N5-M5))*24, 40)`

Comment: Not sure I am understanding you correctly. Could you please implement your suggestion using the code I have above?

Comment: @Tim Williams, some days will not have any hours worked because they are not scheduled to work those days.

Comment: Hence "each day worked" in my comment - I realize there may be empty days.  In full: `=MIN(24*((D5-C5)+(F5-E5)+(H5-G5)+(J5-I5)+(L5-K5)+(N5-M5)),40) - (COUNTA(C5:N5)/2)`  Or something similar - not sure where the lunch hour gets subtracted.

Comment: Presumably there will be cases where someone works a half-day and doesn't take lunch. How do you want your sheet to handle that?

Comment: @TimWilliams, your code works for Monday thru Friday, the hours equal 35 in the Reg. Column but it doesn't go over 35 hours in that column. The way it is supposed to work is that it tally's up the hours worked and displays them in the reg. column up to 40 hours. Then any hours over 40 is shown in the O.T column. The code for the overtime column is:       =IF(((D5-C5)+(F5-E5)+(H5-G5)+(J5-I5)+(L5-K5)+(N5-M5))*24>40,((D5-C5)+(F5-E5)+(H5-G5)+(J5-I5)+(L5-K5)+(N5-M5))*24-40,0)

Comment: `=MIN((24*((D5-C5)+(F5-E5)+(H5-G5)+(J5-I5)+(L5-K5)+(N5-M5)))-(COUNTA(C5:N5)/2), 40)`

Answer (score 0):

Provided you always enter an 'IN' and an 'OUT' time, you could use COUNTA to do so. COUNTA counts the numer of non-blank cells in a range. Half of the non-blank cells equals the number of days worked, hence the number of hours that need to be subtracted.
We also assume that every day worked includes a lunch break.

Your formula would become:

```
=IF(((D5-C5)+(F5-E5)+(H5-G5)+(J5-I5)+(L5-K5)+(N5-M5))-COUNTA(C5:N5)/2*24>40,40,((D5-C5)+(F5-E5)+(H5-G5)+(J5-I5)+(L5-K5)+(N5-M5))-COUNTA(C5:N5)/2*24)
```

Comment: I tried using your code above but it did not even show any number. Can you please see if there is something that is not right?